# Some problems with Flume

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop, cloudera, flume

I have 2 CDH4 Clusters.
One with CentOS 6.4 (Real hardware) other Ubuntu 12.04(Amazon EC2).

All configuration file a made manually same(With Cloudera manager).
I try to start [Cloudera-twitter-example](https://github.com/cloudera/cdh-twitter-example). When I start flume on CentOS cluster it works without any problems. But on Ubuntu cluster Flume gives such error in log file:

```
2013-09-11 15:04:54,491 INFO org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup: Component type: SINK, name: HDFS started
2013-09-11 15:04:54,527 ERROR org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor: Unable to start EventDrivenSourceRunner: { source:com.cloudera.flume.source.TwitterSource
{name:Twitter,state:IDLE} } - Exception follows.
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: twitter4j.FilterQuery.setIncludeEntities(Z)Ltwitter4j/FilterQuery;
```

After some googling i found [this solution in comments](http://www.thecloudavenue.com/2013/03/analyse-tweets-using-flume-hadoop-and.html) by 
Suresh E GopalanAugust 20, 2013 at 2:43 AM

> So we have another JAR file
>   search-contrib-0.9.1-cdh4.3.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar with
>   the same class and conflicting with correct one in FLUME_CLASSPATH
>   Temporarily rename it to .org extension, so that it will be excluded
>   from classpath at the startup

After renaming this jar it Flume start to work on Ubuntu cluster.
On CentOS cluster i have same jar with same Classes but it don't need to be renamed.

Why it happens and What should i do change in Ubuntu cluster to have same behaviour without renaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rebuild the flume-source, don't download the prebuilt snapshot.jar

Comment: Flume-source was build on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes you  are right. I have build it on same ubuntu versions but with different JDK